# htaccess match only (address bar) url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to prevent images from being opened in a new tab.

```
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE} [NC,R,L]
```

but this line is being executed on every request, which is making all images disappear
Is there a flag I can use so that the RewriteRule only executes when the url is in the address bar ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You're dealing with server side programming - it has no idea what happens on the browser.

Pretty much only thing you could check is for a referer, but that's a very weak check, and would not be able to distinguish when opening an image to a new tab. The only case where it might have some effect is when someone would've used a direct link to an image from somewhere else than from your site.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I'll think some other way